# Deleting an object with SQL and updating the Context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using EF and have a context with which I have deleted a row in a table using a simple SQL call through the ExecuteStoreCommand function on the context (I have to do it this way for other reasons). It works fine, but the context doesn't know what happened.

I get a problem later when using the same context when I'm trying to commit some changes because the commit does not give the expected number of affected rows.

My question is, what is the best way to update the context with the changes (deleted rows) that I've made.

I've already tried getting the deleted object and using it in the context refresh function, but it doesn't really work, probably because it (correctly) gets a null reference when trying to get the deleted object.

```
_ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _ctx.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeeId == employeeId));
```

Also, using `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries` doesn't work for me either, because it doesn't know which objects have been deleted.

I do not want to:

- Recreate the context.
- Refresh more than I need to.
- Mess with lazy loading.

I just want to get the context up to date again after deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you must somehow identify deleted entity - if you don't know how you are done and the solution is only a new context):

```
var employee = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(~EntityState.Detached)
                                     .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                                     .Select(e => e.Entity)
                                     .OfType<Employee>()
                                     .FirstOrDefault(e => e...);
if (employee != null) ctx.Detach(employee);
```

Btw. don't use direct SQL modification for attached entities. It is the worst operation you can do. EF doesn't expect this and it is not able to handle it. The best solution in such case is recreating the context.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I'll definitely try that. Will it also work if the object is in a list in another object?I know that I shouldn't use direct SQL modification, but I had to do it in this case for performance.

Comment: This seems to work exactly as I hoped. Would you be able to tell me if it detaches the correct employee object, even if it is part of a list on an existing Company object?

Comment: It should detach it correctly and fix all relationships to not include the reference.